# "I will make you {write / written} this letter."

Tags: infinitives, future-tense, past-participles, future-perfect

> I will **make** you **write** this letter.

or

> I will **make** you **written** this letter.

Which of these two sentences is correct? If both, please, tell me where to use each.

Answer (score 3):

You make someone **do** (bare infinitive) something. The third form (past participle) is not used after *make* in this construction.